# SQlite works slow on an one concrete query

Tags: sqlite

I have SQLite table

```
CREATE TABLE "Storage" (
    "P" VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL,
    "S" VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL,
    "B" BLOB,
    "H" CHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    "P" INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY("P")
);
```

During some transaction my C++ application performs several queries like

```
SELECT H From Storage WHERE P='/bla/blabla/100' //(1)
SELECT S, B From Storage WHERE P='/bla/blabla/100/200' //(2)
SELECT S, B From Storage WHERE P='/bla/blabla/100/300' //(3)
SELECT S, B From Storage WHERE P='/bla/blabla/100/400' //(4)
```

After profiling I figured out that the time of (1) is equal to summarry time of (2), (3), (4)

I tried to use EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN to understand what is going on, but it seems that DB uses a common approach for all these queries:

```
SEARCH TABLE Storage USING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_Storage_1 (Path=?)
```

So I cannot understand why (1) is so long. 
Does someone have an idea?

Comment: If it is always the first one it sounds like some kind of caching may be occurring.

Comment: I came across this article on char and varchar data types. It has to do with the storage of that data and how the comparison happens.  Chances are that if you run it without the 'where' statement they might be equal in performance. https://www.vertabelo.com/blog/comparing-char-and-varchar-data-types-in-different-database-engines/

Comment: Did you try to change order of these queries? Maybe, as andre said, it's related to some kind of caching?